# Simple server - threads are left open if try to stream a file

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm fairly new to rust and I'm trying to learn it by doing [www.rust-class.org](http://www.rust-class.org). In one of the assignments I've to implement simple web server. Most of the code on github is for v0.9 so I had to rewrite some of the things. Anyway:

Webserver code is below but I don't expect you to read everything so down below I highlight the part when the problem occurs.

```
use std::io::*;
use std::io::net::ip::SocketAddr;
use std::{str, os};
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc, Semaphore};
use std::path::{Path, PosixPath};
use std::io::fs::PathExtensions;
use std::collections::{BinaryHeap, HashMap};
use std::io::timer::sleep;
use std::time::duration::Duration;

static CONTENT_TYPE_HTML: &'static str = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n";
static HTTP_SUCCESS: &'static str = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
static HTTP_NOT_FOUND: &'static str = "HTTP/1.1 404 OK\r\n";

static START_COUNTER_STYLE: &'static str = "
  <doctype !html><html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello, Rust!</title>
    <style>
      body { background-color: #884414; color: #FFEEAA}
      h1 { font-size:2cm; text-align: center; color: black; text-shadow: 0 0 4mm red }
      h2 { font-size:2cm; text-align: center; color: black; text-shadow: 0 0 4mm green }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>";
static END_COUNTER_STYLE: &'static str = "</body></html>\r\n";

static FILE_CHUNK: uint = 8192;
static MAX_CONCURRENCY: int = 4;

#[deriving(PartialEq, Eq)]
struct HTTPRequest {
    peer_name: SocketAddr,
    path: PosixPath,
    file_size: uint,
    priority: uint
}

impl PartialOrd for HTTPRequest {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &HTTPRequest) -> Option<Ordering> {
        // Comparison is reversed to make PriorityQueue behave like a min-heap
        (self.priority).partial_cmp(&other.priority)
    }
}

impl Ord for HTTPRequest {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &HTTPRequest) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}

pub struct WebServer {
    port: uint,
    ip_str: String,

    request_queue_arc: Arc<Mutex<BinaryHeap<HTTPRequest>>>,
    stream_map_arc: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<SocketAddr, Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>>>>,

    notify_sender: Sender<()>,
    notify_recv: Receiver<()>,

    www_dir_path: Path,

    concurrency_limit: Arc<Semaphore>,
}

impl WebServer {
    pub fn new(ip_str: String, port: uint, www_dir_str: String) -> WebServer {
        let (notify_sender, notify_recv) = channel();

        let www_dir_path = Path::new(www_dir_str);

        debug!("I'm serving server from directory: {}", www_dir_path.display());

        WebServer {
            ip_str: ip_str,
            port: port,
            www_dir_path: www_dir_path,

            request_queue_arc: Arc::new(Mutex::new(BinaryHeap::new())),
            stream_map_arc: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())),

            notify_sender: notify_sender,
            notify_recv: notify_recv,

            concurrency_limit: Arc::new(Semaphore::new(MAX_CONCURRENCY))
        }
    }

    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        self.listen();
        self.dequeue_static_file_request();
    }

    pub fn listen(&mut self) {
        let addr = from_str::<SocketAddr>(format!("{}:{}", self.ip_str, self.port).as_slice()).expect("Address error.");

        let stream_map_arc = self.stream_map_arc.clone();
        let notify_sender = self.notify_sender.clone();
        let request_queue_arc = self.request_queue_arc.clone();
        let www_dir_path = self.www_dir_path.clone();

        spawn(proc(){
            let mut acceptor = net::tcp::TcpListener::bind(addr).listen();
            println!("Listening on {}", addr);
            let mut requests_counter: uint = 0;

            for stream in acceptor.incoming() {
                match stream.clone() {
                    Ok(mut res) => { res.set_timeout(Some(1000*10)); },
                    Err(why) => { panic!("Couldn't set timout for stream: {}", why.desc); }
                }
                requests_counter += 1;

                let stream_map_arc = stream_map_arc.clone();
                let notify_sender = notify_sender.clone();
                let request_queue_arc = request_queue_arc.clone();
                let www_dir_path = www_dir_path.clone();

                spawn(proc() {
                    let mut stream = stream;
                    let mut buf = [0, ..500];
                    stream.read(&mut buf);
                    let request_str = str::from_utf8(buf.as_slice());

                    debug!("Request:\n{}", request_str);

                    let peer_name: SocketAddr = WebServer::peer_name(stream.clone());

                    match WebServer::get_request_path(www_dir_path.clone(), buf) {
                        Ok(request_path) => {
                            let extension = match request_path.extension_str() {
                                Some(ext) => ext,
                                None => ""
                            };

                            debug!("Requested path :\n{}", request_path.as_str());
                            debug!("Extension :\n{}",extension);

                            if request_path.as_str().expect("Request path err") == "www" {
                                debug!("===== Counter Page request =====");
                                WebServer::respond_with_counter_page(stream, requests_counter);
                                debug!("=====Terminated connection from [{}:{}].=====", peer_name.ip, peer_name.port);
                            } else if request_path.is_file() && (extension == "html" || extension == "bin") {
                                debug!("===== Static page request =====");
                                WebServer::enqueue_static_file_request(
                                    stream,
                                    request_path.clone(),
                                    peer_name,
                                    stream_map_arc,
                                    request_queue_arc,
                                    notify_sender
                                );
                            } else if request_path.is_file() && extension == "html" {
                                debug!("===== Dynamic page request =====");
                                // WebServer::respond_with_dynamic_page(stream, request_path.clone());
                                debug!("=====Terminated connection from [{}:{}].=====", peer_name.ip, peer_name.port);
                            } else {
                                debug!("===== Respond with error page =====");
                                WebServer::respond_with_error_page(stream);
                                debug!("=====Terminated connection from [{}:{}].=====", peer_name.ip, peer_name.port);
                            }
                        },
                        Err(_) => {
                            debug!("===== Respond with error page =====");
                            WebServer::respond_with_error_page(stream);
                            debug!("=====Terminated connection from [{}:{}].=====", peer_name.ip, peer_name.port);
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }

    fn respond_with_counter_page(stream: Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>, requests_counter: uint) {
        WebServer::force_write(stream.clone(), format!("{}{}{}Requests:{}{}",
            HTTP_SUCCESS,
            CONTENT_TYPE_HTML,
            START_COUNTER_STYLE,
            requests_counter,
            END_COUNTER_STYLE
        ).as_bytes())
    }

    fn respond_with_error_page(stream: Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>) {
        WebServer::force_write(stream.clone(), HTTP_NOT_FOUND.as_bytes());
    }

    // fn respond_with_dynamic_page(stream: Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>, request_path: Path) {
    //     // WebServer::respond_with_static_page(stream, request_path);
    // }

    // TODO: Application-layer file caching.
    fn respond_with_static_page(stream: net::tcp::TcpStream, request_path: Path) {
        let mut stream = stream;
        let mut file = match File::open(&request_path) {
            Err(why) => {
                debug!("File couln't be opened because: {} kind: {}", why.desc, why.kind);
                return;
            },
            Ok(f) => { f }
        };

        stream.write(HTTP_SUCCESS.as_bytes());
        stream.write(CONTENT_TYPE_HTML.as_bytes());

        loop {
            let mut buf = vec!();
            match file.push_at_least(FILE_CHUNK, FILE_CHUNK, &mut buf) {
                Err(why) => {
                    debug!("File reading problem: {}, {}", why.kind, why.desc)
                    if buf.len() > 0 {
                        stream.write(buf.as_slice());
                    }
                    return;
                },
                Ok(read_bytes_size) => {
                    match stream.write(buf.as_slice()) {
                        Err(why) => {
                            debug!("Stream broken: desc: {}, kind: {}", why.desc, why.kind);
                            return;
                        },
                        Ok(_) => {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fn enqueue_static_file_request(
        stream: Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>,
        request_path: Path,
        peer_name: SocketAddr,

        stream_map_arc: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<SocketAddr, Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>>>>,
        request_queue_arc: Arc<Mutex<BinaryHeap<HTTPRequest>>>,
        notify_sender: Sender<()>,
    ) {
        debug!("Enqueuing static file, waiting for streams lock... to stream: {}", request_path.display());
        let mut local_map = stream_map_arc.lock();
        local_map.insert(peer_name.clone(), stream);

        debug!("Enqueuing static file, waiting for requests lock...");
        let mut local_req = request_queue_arc.lock();


        local_req.push(
            HTTPRequest {
                peer_name: peer_name.clone(),
                path: request_path.clone(),
                file_size: 1,
                priority: 1
            });

        println!("enqueue_static_file_request: request_queue_arc length: {}", local_req.len());
        println!("enqueue_static_file_request: stream_map_arc length: {}", local_map.len());

        notify_sender.send(());
    }

    fn dequeue_static_file_request(&mut self) {
        let stream_map_arc = self.stream_map_arc.clone();
        let request_queue_arc = self.request_queue_arc.clone();

        loop {
            debug!("Waiting for requests!");
            self.notify_recv.recv();
            debug!("Dequeuing static file, waiting for requests lock...");

            let mut local_req = request_queue_arc.lock();

            match local_req.pop() {
                Some(request) => {
                    println!("dequeue_static_file_request, request_queue_arc length: {}, {}",
                        local_req.len(),
                        &request.path.display()
                    );
                    debug!("Dequeuing static file, waiting for streams lock...");
                    let mut local_map = stream_map_arc.lock();
                    println!("dequeue_static_file_request, stream_map_arc length: {}", local_map.len());

                    match local_map.remove(&request.peer_name) {
                        None => { },
                        Some(stream) => match stream {
                                Ok(res) => {
                                    self.concurrency_limit.acquire();
                                    let child_concurrency_limit = self.concurrency_limit.clone();
                                    let res = res.clone();
                                    spawn(proc(){
                                        WebServer::respond_with_static_page(res, request.path);
                                        child_concurrency_limit.release();
                                        debug!("=====Terminated connection from [{}:{}].=====",
                                            &request.peer_name.ip, &request.peer_name.port
                                        );
                                    });
                                },

                                Err(_) => {
                                    debug!("Stream had broken in the meantime.");
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                None => {}
            }
        }
    }

    fn peer_name(stream: Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>) -> net::ip::SocketAddr {
        match stream {
            Err(_) => panic!("Stream broken @ peer_name"),
            Ok(res) => {
                match res.clone().peer_name() {
                    Ok(addr) => addr,
                    Err(_) => panic!("Couldn't obtain peername from stream")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fn get_request_path(root: Path, buf: [u8, ..500]) -> Result<Path, &'static str> {
        match str::from_utf8(buf.as_slice()) {
            Some(request_str) => {
                let request_headers: Vec<&str> = request_str.splitn(3, ' ').collect();
                if request_headers.len() == 4 {
                    Ok(root.join(Path::new(format!("./{}", request_headers[1]))))
                } else {
                    Err("Bad headers")
                }
            },
            None => {
                Err("Empty headers")
            }
        }
    }

    fn force_write(stream: Result<net::tcp::TcpStream, IoError>, content: &[u8]) {
        let mut stream = stream;

        match stream.as_mut() {
            Err(_) => { debug!("Well. I wanted to safetly write to a... BROKEN stream."); },
            Ok(res) => {
                // ?? wtf
                match res.write(content) {
                    Err(_) => { },
                    Ok(_) => { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to stream a file I'm getting threads(due to the streams not freed?) left open and RAM usage is increasing slowly. I've narrowed it down to the streaming part because for instance if I'll put `sleep(Duration::seconds(2))` and not try to stream a file, the queue will grow and over time go back to zero. Such thing doesn't happen when I try to stream a file.

Clean state:

[image: Clean state]

After running httpref:

[image: After runnig httpref]

And future requests are waiting forever for streams lock. I've tried hunting for infinite loops somewhere but without a success - everything seems to work fine.

Do you have any suggestion what might cause such behavior?

Comment: In general, yes. 0.9 was a _very_ long time ago. Some stuff will be very different.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your "Content-Length" header assuming the content of the file is loaded into `body` or you can get len some other way try

```
    stream.write(HTTP_SUCCESS.as_bytes());
    stream.write(CONTENT_TYPE_HTML.as_bytes());
    stream.write(format!("Content-length: {}", body.len())).unwrap();
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't solve the problem but thanks for pointing out that I should have included content-length header!